# Can you read/write to a Excel document with HTML?

Tags: html, excel, database

I'm trying to create a basic functioning website, which probably needs a database, however that is a little out of my depth at the moment.
I was wondering if I could write data into an excel document and then have a website pick this data up from that excel spreadsheet and use it to update the website, i.e to use it to change a specific variable.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: No, you can't use HTML to write to an Excel document. HTML is a markup language used to describe a web page's visual elements. File I/O is a job for a programming/scripting language, such as JavaScript or PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you read/write to a Excel document with HTML?

No. HTML is not a programming language, and by itself would not be able to accomplish any of the steps needed to make this happen.

> ... could [I] write data into an excel document and then have a website pick this data up from that excel spreadsheet and use it to update the website, i.e to use it to change a specific variable

Yes. Although it would be difficult to achieve this in an automatic way (i.e. website automatically updates upon change). For that you would need to build an excel plugin, and even then it may not be fully automatic. Besides that, it is possible to import data from an excel spreadsheet into a website.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's really helpful

Comment: No problem, please vote on my comment if you want :)